# How to define array of hash objects in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

There are plenty of answers that allow us to achieve this like so:

`array = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]`. But what I'm looking for is something more closer to c++ or java implementation.

In C++ we can define an array of pairs like so:

```cpp
map <pair<int,int>,int> mp;
```

and perhaps use it for assigning values like:

```cpp
mp[{x1,y1}] = 1;
```

Or to check if some element exist like so:

```cpp
while(range(x,y) && !mp[{x,y}]) {
    x += xx;
    y += yy;
    ans++;
 }
```

Now the question is, how can we define our array of hashes similar to c++ where we have something like:

```
 array = [{1,1}: 1, {2,2}: 2, {3,3}: 3]
```

Comment: Your last line says what you want, but it's not clear what you are given to produce that. Is it `a = [1,2,3]`? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: yes @CarySwoveland

Comment: `{1,1}` is not a valid Ruby object. Do you mean the array`[1,1]`?

Comment: yeh sorry, I'll update my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

a.map { |e| { [e,e] => e } }
  #=> [{[1, 1]=>1}, {[2, 2]=>2}, {[3, 3]=>3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby maps are called [Hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html). A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. The key of the hash can be of any type: number, symbol, string, array, other hash, etc.

So you could write it as a hash, where keys are arrays:

```
hash = {[1, 1] => 1, [2, 2] => 2, [3, 3] => 3}
# => {[1, 1]=>1, [2, 2]=>2, [3, 3]=>3} 

hash[[2, 2]]
# => 2

hash[[12, 34]] = 55
# => 55 

hash
# => {[1, 1]=>1, [2, 2]=>2, [3, 3]=>3, [12, 34]=>55}
```